# Is there a way to cleanly store turnips?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

When I'm buying turnips and don't want to keep them several days in my pockets, I go to my home to store them. However, it's not possible to put them in the storage space, while there's plenty of room left. So, I ended up putting them on the floor. Is there another way to store them?

I have a fridge but when opening it, it asks me if I want to change my clothes... So this is not an option.

Comment: I've got a basement with a golden floor and walls to act as a treasure vault. If we don't get storage options, we _make_ storage options.

Comment: @Flater Aha. Exactly what I was thinking about! 
I just finished building my first floor. When loan will be paid, basement here I am!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, I ended up putting them on the floor. Is there another way to store them?

Sadly [no](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidthier/2020/04/19/how-to-store-turnips-in-animal-crossing-new-horizons/). We can only hope for an update to add another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just drop turnips on the ground outside to store them.  They won't spoil, but they can be picked up by visitors or anyone who shares your island.  Putting a fence around them protects them from visitors, but not best friend visitors or shared island players, so you'd have to trust them.