# Where can I safely leave turnips?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I want to make sure my precious stalk market commodities are protected. Would it be safe to leave them outside or will they rot? What if I just leave them in my basement?

Comment: Closely related (but not duplicate) question: [Is there a way to cleanly store turnips?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368399/145980)

Comment: @MageXy As someone who doesn't play the game, what makes the questions different?

Comment: @Wrigglenite The other question is asking what storage possibilities exist for turnips, since they can't be put into the house storage. This question is asking whether it is safe to leave turnips on the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turnips cannot be put into your storage, so unfortunately that means the only way to "store" them is to either keep them in your inventory (not really viable if you buy in bulk) or to drop them on the floor.

There's a couple of minor problems with dropping turnips on the floor, depending on how you play. If you're doing singleplayer, you're probably fine. You have to make sure to sell them before the next Sunday otherwise they will rot - this is always the case anyways, so no change there. The only catch is that if you're storing them outside, they may count against you in your island rating because villagers will complain about too many items littering the floor. Since you're just using the space for temporary turnips storage, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

However, if you do multiplayer, you need to be a little more careful with your turnips since anyone can pick them up and steal them. If you're like me and you like to invite random people to your island (for trading, exploration, catalog exchange, etc.), then you need to make sure your turnips are inaccessible to any visitors. Luckily, this is pretty easy. If you have your turnips inside, just make sure they are all in one room and then simply block that room off with furniture. You can't move furniture or decorations around while you have visitors ("it's rude to redecorate while you have guests"), and neither can the visitors. Alternatively, if you're outside of your house, you can simply fence them off. Again, visitors can't edit your island so they won't be able to grab your turnips through the fence.

Comment: I've heard of some people getting ants for leaving them outside - does that only happen if you don't sale them by Sunday?

Comment: @Rapida Rotten turnips attract ants if they are outside. Turnips will rot on the Sunday after you purchased them (i.e., after 1 week).